# rbindlist function to keep data frames with 0 rows in output

Tags: r, list, data.table, data-mining

I have a list of data frames `df_list` that I would like to convert into a single data frame `out_df`. This is simple with the function `rbindlist` but my only issue here is that only non-empty dataframes will be kept in the output dataframe.

I know the fill option fills missing columns with NAs by using:

```
out_df<- rbindlist(df_list, fill=TRUE)
```

But what I want to do as well is to keep and fill missing rows from the input list. What would be the way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a row with `NA` values into the empty data.frames? It is unclear what output you expect.

Comment: Yes that will be a manual option to do it. Basically I would like to do this in a more automatised way so that I do not have to check which data frames have empty rows in a scenario where my list is made of many data frames.

Comment: lapply will do it in automated way. you can pass lapply call into rbindlist. f=function(x) if(!nrow(x)) x[1] else x

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new list which replaces any empty `data.table` with one with an `NA` row.

```r
# Create some data
dt1 <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = letters[1:3])
dt2 <- data.table(a = numeric(0), b = character(0))
dt3 <- dt1

l <- list(dt1, dt2, dt3)
```

One way to do this is through coercing an empty matrix:

```r
l2 <- lapply(l, \(dt) {
    if (nrow(dt) == 0) {
        col_names <- names(dt)
        dt <- matrix(ncol = ncol(dt)) |>
            data.table() |>
            setNames(col_names)
    }
    dt
})
```

The important thing is to make sure we are not copying the entirety of the data. We can check that by making sure that an unchanged `data.table` has the same memory address:

```r
tracemem(dt1) == tracemem(l[[1]]) # TRUE
tracemem(l[[1]]) == tracemem(l2[[1]]) # TRUE
```

```r
rbindlist(l2)
#     a    b
# 1:  1    a
# 2:  2    b
# 3:  3    c
# 4: NA <NA>
# 5:  1    a
# 6:  2    b
# 7:  3    c
```